# python - json loads, how to clear line breaks from outside of key value pairs but keep them within values?

Tags: python, json

We receive AWS notifications to an automated mailbox in JSON format, I have a python script that should process these, however when im loading the content/body of these emails into JSON it is erroring with

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 5 column 3007 (char 3159)`

When I looked at the content I can see it is full of line breaks where it seems the json has been formatted for readability in the body of the message. I need to maintain the line breaks in the values of the data but outside of the values they need stripping so I can load the content into readable JSON

here is a sample of the content, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

```json
'{\r\n  "Type" : "Notification",\r\n  "MessageId" : "afad72049c0cb1",\r\n  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:793738:aws-health",\r\n  "Message" : "{\\"version\\":\\"0\\",\\"id\\":\\"3f059336-bdd1-e27b423d5\\",\\"detail-type\\":\\"AWS Health Event\\",\\"source\\":\\"aws.health\\",\\"account\\":\\"7954138\\",\\"time\\":\\"2022-10-19T08:55:00Z\\",\\"region\\":\\"eu-west-1\\",\\"resources\\":[\\"docker/b\\",\\"master/phub\\"],\\"detail\\":{\\"eventArn\\":\\"arn:aws:health:eu-west-1::event/ECS/AWS_ECS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION/AWS_ECS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION_3986a573dbe33a823860ad3272f72e\\",\\"service\\":\\"ECS\\",\\"eventTypeCode\\":\\"AWS_ECS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION\\",\\"eventTypeCategory\\":\\"accountNotification\\",\\"startTime\\":\\"Wed, 19 Oct 2022 08:55:00 GMT\\",\\"eventDescription\\":[{\\"language\\":\\"en_US\\",\\"latestDescription\\":\\"A software update has been deployed to Fargate which includes CVE patches or other critical patches. No action is required on your part. All new tasks launched automatically uses the latest software version. For running tasks, your tasks need to be restarted in order for these updates to apply. Your tasks running as part of the following ECS Services will be automatically updated beginning October 31, 2022.\\\\n\\\\nA list of your affected resource(s) can be found in the \'Affected resources\' tab in the \\\\\\"Cluster | Service\\\\\\" format.\\\\n\\\\nAfter October 31, 2022, Fargate will begin gradually restarting these tasks. Typically, services should see little to no interruption during the update and no action is required. Data your task has stored on local ephemeral storage will no longer be available, similar to a scaling down event. If you would like to control the timing of this restart you can update the service before October 31, 2022, by running the update-service command from the ECS command-line interface specifying force-new-deployment. For example:\\\\n\\\\n$ aws ecs update-service --service service_name \\\\\\\\\\\\n--cluster cluster_name --force-new-deployment\\\\n\\\\nFor further details on Fargate\'s update process, please refer to the ECS developer guide [1].\\\\n\\\\nIf you have any questions or concerns, please contact AWS Support [2].\\\\n\\\\n[1] https://eur02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.aws.amazon.com%2FAmazonECS%2Flatest%2Fuserguide%2Ftask-maintenance.html%2F%2Fn&amp;data=05%7C01%7Cnetguru%40domain.com%7C18ecb8a6d7454302640808dab1df762e%7C9168a104f43a47ffa70848b8545e1691%7C0%7C0%7C638017870565849523%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&amp;sdata=8GnV6bDohXEG8AYo4mOwSY9dLuqRLknLuXnaelVS%2FnI%3D&amp;reserved=0[2] https://eur02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Faws.amazon.com%2Fsupport%2F%2F762e%7C9168a104f43a47ffa70848b8545e1691%7C0%7C0%7C638017870565849523%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&amp;sdata=Ll8kJRsNgFw46znXWhmH9Ph%2Bu2zBchweMzqq1feqjQk%3D&amp;reserved=0"}],\\"affectedEntities\\":[{\\"entityValue\\":\\"docker/rcure-hub\\"},{\\"entityValue\\":\\"master/rcure-hub\\"}]}}",\r\n  "Timestamp" : "2022-10-19T14:37:30.976Z",\r\n  "SignatureVersion" : "1",\r\n  "Signature" : "taT/Hxpaywf/WurHI/hs0wmZxA0hqhjDX1tFk9KmmY2Vyj6zXTzF6k78XoSiLvfGK7pOZCL+oruqZKBFyRy8SvKvDMa0ZT6ekKj9uAEwmpAItDZfkNvJM1hmSSNEV+8SpKRBU0GSQ8v4UkXMHQUNqGIURKRJpoJEORy8Yd7/Qsw8cNlZhrEAGzj/L7O6Fo84cUsjBASqDyjOwAnUmys0CVdxrEUYPoc6m4tPfazrTkw+GSteBQ904kSvSbEL7AR61n7TK4nqv6t3xJ7HcEiP6vO0m7mj3rhOjIgeFtQrPbFONUHdWt3hP1OD9Fa84tVEwPDHJiFm+w0+aJu+WhEUTg==",\r\n  "SigningCertURL" : "https://eur02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com%2FSimpleNotificationService-56e67fcb41f6fec09b0196692625d385.pem&amp;data=05%7C01%7Cnetguru%40domain.com%7C18ecb8a6d7454302640808dab1df762e%7C9168a104f43a47ffa70848b8545e1691%7C0%7C0%7C638017870565849523%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&amp;sdata=8%2BWv%2FP64OBM3lk0CXurmLbYlIZCxHoR%2BeWCbWZUoUQw%3D&amp;reserved=0",\r\n  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://eur02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com%2F%3FAction%3DUnsubscribe%26SubscriptionArn%3Darn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aeu-west-1%3A793726854138%3Aaws-health%3A6de24e4d-ae74-4aaa-bf78-36b6e95c335f&amp;data=05%7C01%7Cnetguru%40domain.com%7C18ecb8a6d7454302640808dab1df762e%7C9168a104f43a47ffa70848b8545e1691%7C0%7C0%7C6V%2FvQ6tB2outb%2FrNzKRsJMJ3DE%3D&amp;reserved=0"\r\n}\r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: How are you reading the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line breaks are not the problem, those line breaks don't invalidate the JSON format, so the `json` module handles them just fine.  The problem is that the string you've provided as an example is not valid JSON. So, if I open up a REPL and do `s = <string you provided>`:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jarrivillaga/miniconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jarrivillaga/miniconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 5 column 2828 (char 2952)
```

Now, going off of the error message, let's look at the 5th line (it's the big one):

```
>>> s.splitlines()[4]
'  "Message" : "{\\"version\\":\\"0\\",\\"id\\":\\"3f059336-bdd1-e27b423d5\\",\\"detail-type\\":\\"AWS Health Event\\",\\"source\\":\\"aws.health\\",\\"account\\":\\"7954138\\",\\"time\\":\\"2022-10-19T08:55:00Z\\",\\"region\\":\\"eu-west-1\\",\\"resources\\":[\\"docker/b\\",\\"master/phub\\"],\\"detail\\":{\\"eventArn\\":\\"arn:aws:health:eu-west-1::event/ECS/AWS_ECS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION/AWS_ECS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION_3986a573dbe33a823860ad3272f72e\\",\\"service\\":\\"ECS\\",\\"eventTypeCode\\":\\"AWS_ECS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION\\",\\"eventTypeCategory\\":\\"accountNotification\\",\\"startTime\\":\\"Wed, 19 Oct 2022 08:55:00 GMT\\",\\"eventDescription\\":[{\\"language\\":\\"en_US\\",\\"latestDescription\\":\\"A software update has been deployed to Fargate which includes CVE patches or other critical patches. No action is required on your part. All new tasks launched automatically uses the latest software version. For running tasks, your tasks need to be restarted in order for these updates to apply. Your tasks running as part of the following ECS Services will be automatically updated beginning October 31, 2022.\\\\n\\\\nA list of your affected resource(s) can be found in the \'Affected resources\' tab in the \\\\\\"Cluster | Service\\\\\\" format.\\\\n\\\\nAfter October 31, 2022, Fargate will begin gradually restarting these tasks. Typically, services should see little to no interruption during the update and no action is required. Data your task has stored on local ephemeral storage will no longer be available, similar to a scaling down event. If you would like to control the timing of this restart you can update the service before October 31, 2022, by running the update-service command from the ECS command-line interface specifying force-new-deployment. For example:\\\\n\\\\n$ aws ecs update-service --service service_name \\\\\\\\\\\\n--cluster cluster_name --force-new-deployment\\\\n\\\\nFor further details on Fargate\'s update process, please refer to the ECS developer guide [1].\\\\n\\\\nIf you have any questions or concerns, please contact AWS Support [2].\\\\n\\\\n[1] https://eur02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.aws.amazon.com%2FAmazonECS%2Flatest%2Fuserguide%2Ftask-maintenance.html%2F%2Fn&amp;data=05%7C01%7Cnetguru%40domain.com%7C18ecb8a6d7454302640808dab1df762e%7C9168a104f43a47ffa70848b8545e1691%7C0%7C0%7C638017870565849523%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&amp;sdata=8GnV6bDohXEG8AYo4mOwSY9dLuqRLknLuXnaelVS%2FnI%3D&amp;reserved=0[2] https://eur02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Faws.amazon.com%2Fsupport%2F%2F762e%7C9168a104f43a47ffa70848b8545e1691%7C0%7C0%7C638017870565849523%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&amp;sdata=Ll8kJRsNgFw46znXWhmH9Ph%2Bu2zBchweMzqq1feqjQk%3D&amp;reserved=0"}],\\"affectedEntities\\":[{\\"entityValue\\":\\"docker/rcure-hub\\"},{\\"entityValue\\":\\"master/rcure-hub\\"}]}}",'
```

Now, let's take a closer look at the problematic portion, column 2828 (char 2952):

```
>>> s[2952-1]
'}'
>>> s.splitlines()[4][2828 - 10: 2828+ 10]
'erved=0"}],\\"affecte'
```

So, this string has an un-escaped quote, ending the JSON string. This is the problem, not the line breaks. Are you sure this is *exactly* what you are getting from AWS? If so, then this is a problem on their end I'd say. But what exactly do you mean by "We receive AWS notifications to an automated mailbox in JSON format"?

Comment: Yes you can subscribe to AWS notifications of your systems and choose the source as JSON, I read the content of the email body directly without any alterations. seems odd AWS would make a mistake with it, is there any regex patterns I could use that would cleanse it all and future proof any errors?

Comment: I found the issue using this advice, it turns out outlook safelinks had been turned on and the URLS in the AWS JSON were being transformed into safe link URLs and then breaking the JSON format

Answer (score -1):

If you want to load this data in JSON format try doing

```
dumps = json.dumps('{\r\n  "Type" :"Notification",\r\n...........;reserved=0"\r\n}\r\n\r\n')
data = json.loads(dumps)
```

Comment: this gives you back the exact same string, which doesn't solve the OP's problem.